# Deserializing fails for a class implementing Collection with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "item": [
    { "foo": 1 },
    { "foo": 2 }
  ]
}
```

This is basically an object that contains a collection of items.

So I made a class to deserialize that:

```
public class ItemList {
  @JsonProperty("item")
  List<Item> items;

  // Getters, setters & co.
  // ...
}
```

**Everything is working nicely up to this point.**

Now, To make my life easier somewhere else, I decided that it would be nice to be able to iterate on the ItemList object and let it implement the Collection interface.

So basically my class became:

```
public class ItemList implements Collection<Item>, Iterable<Item> {
  @JsonProperty("item")
  List<Item> items;

  // Getters, setters & co.

  // Generated all method delegates to items. For instance:
  public Item get(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
  }
}
```

The implementation works properly and nicely. However, the deserialization now fails.

Looks like Jackson is getting confused:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   deserialize instance of com.example.ItemList out of START_OBJECT token

I have tried to add `@JsonDeserialize(as=ItemList.class)` but it did not do the trick.

What's the way to go?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet will be able to answer this. In addition, you might be able to find some useful information in http://stackoverflow.com/a/21279016/1382251.

Comment: While this is a good question as-is, if all you want is to iterate, why make your class a collection instead of just iterable?

Comment: @chrylis: so that I can `for (Item t : itemList)`

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. The enhanced for loop only requires `Iterable`.

Comment: @chrylis: true, it was something else, some code was using List.addAll (which requires Collection). Nothing dramatic though, but I wanted to make it clean so that a list can be added to another list. And same goes with other APIs that may require collections (like Comparator I think or sorting & co.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously it does not work because Jackson uses the standard collection deserialiser for Java collection types which knows nothing about `ItemList` properties.

It is possible to make it work but not in a very elegant way. You need to configure `ObjectMapper` to replace the default collection deserialiser on a bean deserialiser created manually for the corresponding type.  I have written an example that does this in `BeanDeserializerModifier` for all the classes annotated with a custom annotation.

Note that I have to override `ObjectMapper` to get access to a protected method `createDeserializationContext` of `ObjectMapper` to create a proper deserialisation context since the bean modifier does not have access to it.

Here is the code:

```
public class JacksonCustomList {
    public static final String JSON = "{\n" +
            "  \"item\": [\n" +
            "    { \"foo\": 1 },\n" +
            "    { \"foo\": 2 }\n" +
            "  ]\n" +
            "} ";

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public static @interface PreferBeanDeserializer {

    }

    public static class Item {
        public int foo;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(foo);
        }
    }

    @PreferBeanDeserializer
    public static class ItemList extends ArrayList<Item> {
        @JsonProperty("item")
        public List<Item> items;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return items.toString();
        }
    }

    public static class Modifier extends BeanDeserializerModifier {
        private final MyObjectMapper mapper;

        public Modifier(final MyObjectMapper mapper) {
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }

        @Override
        public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyCollectionDeserializer(
                final DeserializationConfig config,
                final CollectionType type,
                final BeanDescription beanDesc,
                final JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
            if (type.getRawClass().getAnnotation(PreferBeanDeserializer.class) != null) {
                DeserializationContext context = mapper.createContext(config);
                try {
                    return context.getFactory().createBeanDeserializer(context, type, beanDesc);
                } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                   throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                }

            }
            return super.modifyCollectionDeserializer(config, type, beanDesc, deserializer);
        }
    }

    public static class MyObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
        public DeserializationContext createContext(final DeserializationConfig cfg) {
            return super.createDeserializationContext(getDeserializationContext().getParser(), cfg);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final MyObjectMapper mapper = new MyObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.setDeserializerModifier(new Modifier(mapper));

        mapper.registerModule(module);
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(JSON, ItemList.class));
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 Nice. I've spent a couple of hours trying to come up with a similar solution using `BeanDeserializerModifier.modifyCollectionDeserializer`, but couldn't figure out how to obtain a `DeserializationContext`.

Comment: Looks like an elegant way to handle that, I'll give it a try.

Comment: One suggestion: instead of sub-classing `ObjectMapper`, you should be able to combine `ContextualDeserializer` with custom Collection deserializer: this gives you access to find/modify value deserializer that is needed, and also guarantees it will be properly initialized. It may make sense to have a look at default collection serializers to handle some special cases (support for polymorphic types).

Answer (score 2):

If you consider the `item` property to be the root value, you can than change your `ItemList` class as follows, using the `@JsonRootName` [annotation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations):

```
@JsonRootName("item")
public class ItemList implements Collection<Item>, Iterable<Item> {
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public Item get(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    // implemented methods deferring to delegate
    // ...
}
```

If you then activate the `UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE` [deserialization feature](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features), things work as expected:

```
String json = "{\"item\": [{\"foo\": 1}, {\"foo\": 2}]}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectReader reader = mapper.reader(ItemList.class);

ItemList itemList = reader
        .with(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE)
        .readValue(json);
```

Serialization works equally well, with the `WRAP_ROOT_VALUE` [serialization feature](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Serialization-Features) enabled:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer();

Item item1 = new Item();
item1.setFoo(1);

Item item2 = new Item();
item2.setFoo(2);

ItemList itemList = new ItemList();
itemList.add(item1);
itemList.add(item2);

String json = writer
        .with(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE)
        .writeValueAsString(itemList);

// json contains {"item":[{"foo":1},{"foo":2}]}
```

This solution will obviously not suffice if your `ItemList` contains additional properties (other than the actual list) that will also need to be serialized/deserialized.

Comment: Nice workaround, but I'd like to keep the possibility of handling extra properties for the future.