# POST method is not inserting data into the two database tables

Tags: java, arrays, json, rest, rest-assured

I'm using RestAssured to test an API.

I have the following, wow can I test the post method?

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "email": "test@email.com",
    "occupation": [{
        "id": 1,
        "feature": {
            "id": 2 
         },
        "company": 7777,
    }]
}
```

"Occupation" is another table, how can I on both tables?
I have tried this:

```
.body("{\"name\": \"test\", \"email\": \"test@email.com\", \"occupation\": {\"id\": 15, \"feature\": {\"id\": 15}", \"company\": \"7777\"}}")
```

But the error

> "Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of
>   START_OBJECT token"

is shown.

Comment: You asking for help with server code, but not showing us the code, so how did you expect us to help you?

Comment: maybe we need some more details.. like your controller for example..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START\_OBJECT token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837856/can-not-deserialize-instance-of-java-util-arraylist-out-of-start-object-token)

Comment: I did not show the code, because I do not have it. I'm just testing the API.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> {\"id\": 15, \"feature\": {\"id\": 15}", \"company\": \"7777\"}}"

Try using JSON array here, too!

f.e.:
[{\"id\": 1, \"feature\": {\"id\": 2}", \"company\": \"7777\"}]"

Comment: There is no `id: 15` in the question, and the object with `id` is already in a JSON array.

Comment: right, replace first 15 with 1 and second with 2.

Comment: Uow! It worked! Thak you so much!