# convert json string to a list of objects in java

Tags: java, json, maven

I'm trying to convert a json string to a list of objects in java.

code:

```
List<StopEta> list = mapper.readValue(string, new TypeReference<List<Pairs>>(){});
```

error:

> Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of
>   START_OBJECT token

string equals to:

```
{"pairs":[{"pair1":2,"pair2":2},{"pair1":1,"pair2":1}]}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START\_OBJECT token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837856/can-not-deserialize-instance-of-java-util-arraylist-out-of-start-object-token)

Comment: It's not a list resp. array at the root of the JSON ...

Comment: try gson api's check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554217/google-gson-deserialize-listclass-object-generic-type