# How to receive randomly generated json value from Firebase using Spring Rest Template?

Tags: java, spring, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, resttemplate

I am trying to get the data from `firebase` using RestAPI. So i have integrated with Spring RestTemplate to receive the GET data. My json as below

```
{
  "alanisawesome": {
    "city": "US",
    "name": "XYZ school"
  },
  "gracehop": {
    "city": "CA",
    "name": "ABC school"
  },
  "nextVal": {
    "city": "Mumbai",
    "name": "GHI School"
  }
}
```

Since Firebase key(`alanisawesome`,`gracehop`,`nextVal`) created automatically by firebase, I am unable to fetch based on the key.

My Spring Boot code is,

```
return restTemplate
        .getForObject("https:<FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com/School.json",
            School.class);
```

My model class is,

```
public class School {

  private String name;
  private String city;

// Getters and Setters

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [REST template `getForObject` method](https://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate) is meant to be used with singular objects. So you can use it to get a single school, with:

```
restTemplate
    .getForObject("https:<FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com/School/alanisawesome.json", School.class);
```

But your `School.json` has the data for multiple schools under it, with unknown keys. This means you can't use `getForObject` with the `School.class` directly.

This [tutorial has a section on either using a `ParameterizedTypeReference`, or a wrapper class](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-list#get-list), which both sound promising. For you that means you'd either need to use `new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<School>>`, or would need to create a `SchoolList` class.

Comment: I tried with ParameterizedTypeReference which throws `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT` and I tried WrapperClass also which gives `null response`. Could you please help

Comment: It looks like it doesn't recognize the structure as a `List`. This makes sense in hindsight, as an object has meaningful keys, which must be read too. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837856/can-not-deserialize-instance-of-java-util-arraylist-out-of-start-object-token (the first result I get when I search for the error message you shared), and it seems that a `Collection` might be the way to go.