# How to get list of entities from list of Ids in springBoot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

my requirement is to get the list of entity from the list of ids , I was trying something like this and I when I am priting to string method I am getting the list but when I am trying to return it , It saying not found .

My repo code

```
  List<AddingProductForView> findAllByproductidIn(ArrayList<Integer> productid);
```

my servicecode:-

```
   public List<AddingProductForView> getListOfData(ArrayList<Integer> productid){
        List<AddingProductForView> findAllByProductIdIn = repository.findAllByproductidIn(productid);
         return findAllByProductIdIn;
    }
```

mycontrollercode:-

```
    @PostMapping("/getProductsId")
public List<AddingProductForView> getListOfData(@RequestBody ArrayList<Integer> productid) {
    List<AddingProductForView> findAllByProductIdIn = fileService.getListOfData(productid);
    return findAllByProductIdIn;
}
```

while priting toString method (getting the result as :-

```
`[AddingProductForView [productid=1, productname=RO, imagepath=./assets/1.jpeg, price=4000  , productdescription=best], AddingProductForView [productid=2, productname=RO, imagepath=./assets/2.jpeg, price=8000  , productdescription=cheap], AddingProductForView [productid=3, productname=RO, imagepath=./assets/3.jpeg, price=2000  , productdescription=values]]`
```

What I am trying to hit from postman:-

```
  [1,3,2]
```

Error:- {
"timestamp": "2021-07-02T07:25:50.973+0000",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/api/excel/getProductsId"
}

Comment: and what is actual problem here?

Comment: questionUpdated@rkosegi

Comment: try put {"productId":[1,2,3]} in postman request body, you should tell us what is your problem, and what you want to do @DivyeshKumar

Comment: badRequest , QuestionUpdated @Dolphin

Comment: try to put what I told to the postman body @DivyeshKumar

Comment: the exception is for the same what you said @Dolphin

Comment: do you have a public api from public domain network I could Invoke? @DivyeshKumar

Comment: no its not in public domain , its in local as of now @Dolphin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START\_OBJECT token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837856/can-not-deserialize-instance-of-java-util-arraylist-out-of-start-object-token)

Answer (score 1):

Your controller code is:

```
@PostMapping("/getProductsByIds")
```

but the url you type in postman is:

```
"path": "/api/excel/getProductsId"
```

Comment: I have requestmapping defined at class level something like this :- @RequestMapping("/api/excel")

Comment: I mean `getProductsByIds` vs `getProductsId`

Answer (score 0):

Just change signature of method : ArrayList to interface List

```
public List<AddingProductForView> getListOfData(@RequestBody List<Integer> productid)
```

Answer (score 0):

we have to use @ResponseBody at the method level for such

```
@PostMapping("/getProductsId")
@ResponseBody
public List<AddingProductForView> getListOfData(@RequestBody List<Integer> productid) {
    List<AddingProductForView> findAllByProductIdIn = fileService.getListOfData(productid);
    return findAllByProductIdIn;
}
```

Comment: No, this thing is not required. Because at the top, You mentioned '@RestController' and It's a combination of '@Controller' and '@ResponseBody'.